# Find an approximate expression of a sum of a product using the average of each item

Tags: sumsets

Is it possible to find an approximate expression of $\frac{\sum_{i=1}^{n} k_i x_i}{\sum_{i=1}^{n} k_i}$ using $\langle k \rangle$, $\langle k^2 \rangle$, $\langle x \rangle$, and $n$? Alternatively if it is possible to express the boundary (biggest and smallest possible value) of $\frac{\sum_{i=1}^{n} k_i x_i}{\sum_{i=1}^{n} k_i}$ using $\langle k \rangle$, $\langle k^2 \rangle$, $\langle x \rangle$ and $n$?

Here: $\langle k \rangle=\frac{\sum_{i=1}^{n} k_i}{n}$, $\langle k^2 \rangle=\frac{\sum_{i=1}^{n} k_i^2}{n}$, $\langle x \rangle=\frac{\sum_{i=1}^{n} x_i}{n}$, $k_i \geq 0$ is an integer, and $0\leq x_i\leq 1$.

Comment: Approximate, yes. Meaningful? Unlikely.  Take a long bar and divide it into n varying commensurable lengths, one length for each k_i.  The average of the square values gives some information, I saynot enough: take the average of the x's to be 1/2, then color the 1/2 shortest segments one color, and the remaining longest segments another.  That represents your variability when you know the average x value.  The square average may weakly measure that variability, but it does not say where the desired value (sum of colored lengths) lives.  Gerhard "Ask Me About System Design" Paseman, 2012.04.18

Comment: $n\langle x\rangle$ is a (trivial) upper bound, and is attained when the $x_i$ are all equal, regardless of the distribution of the $k_i$. 

Comment: @Gerry, I think you mean $\langle x \rangle$, not $n\langle x \rangle$, too (see my comment to Aaron Meyerowitz's answer).  I'm not sure why the OP bothers putting what amounts to an $n\langle k \rangle$ in the denominator of what he wants to express in terms of $\langle k \rangle$ etc.

Comment: @Barry, right you are, of course. 

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We must assume that $\langle k \rangle \ne 0.$ When $n=1$ we know everything.

Certainly $\langle k^2\rangle  \ge\langle k\rangle ^2.$  If $\langle k^2\rangle  =\langle k\rangle ^2$ then the $k_i$ are all equal (to $\langle k \rangle$ ) and $\frac{\sum_{i=1}^{n} k_i x_i}{\sum_{i=1}^{n} k_i}=\langle x \rangle$ exactly. The same thing happens if all the $x_i$ are equal although we have no way of know from the given information if that is the case. Also knowing $\sum_{i=1}^{n} x_i^2$ would be helpful. Then $\sum_{i=1}^{n} k_i x_i=C\sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^{n} k_i^2\sum_{i=1}^{n} x_i^2}$ for some $0 \le C \le 1.$

In the special case that $n=3$,  and $\langle k^2 \rangle=30$ we can figure that the $k_i$ are $1,2,5$ in some order (given that they are integers). I will ignore these number theoretic features and only assume that the $k_i$ are non-negative reals.

We may assume that $\max_i{x_i}=x_1.$ When $\langle k^2 \rangle \gt \langle k \rangle^2$ (i.e. the $k_i$ are not all equal) all we can say with the given information is that $0 \le \frac{\sum_{i=1}^{n} k_i x_i}{\sum_{i=1}^{n} k_i} \le x_1.$ Equality occurs when $k_1 \gt 0$ but $k_i=0$ for $i \gt 1.$ That only one of the $k_i$ is non-zero can be discovered from $\langle k^2 \rangle =n\langle k \rangle^2$ Now $\max_i{x_i} \le \sum_{i=1}^{n} x_i=n\langle x \rangle$ with equality when  $x_i=0$ for $i \ge 2.$

**Earlier** Careless reading lead me to mention: If the $k_i$ are not all equal, and some of the $x_i$ can be negative, then nothing can be deduced. even if we actually know all of the $k_i.$ Let us assume that $k_2=k_1+\epsilon.$ Assume first that $n=2$. Then given  desired values $\langle x \rangle=m$ and $\frac{\sum_{i=1}^{n} k_i x_i}{\sum_{i=1}^{n} k_i}=S$ we must take $x_1=m+\delta$ and $x_2=m-\delta$ for $\delta=\frac{(S-m)(2k_1+\epsilon)}{\epsilon}.$ For larger $n$ I can volunteer the extra information that $x_i=0$ for all $i \gt 2$ and adjust the formulas slightly.

Comment: In your "Certainly" sentence, I think you mean just "$\langle x \rangle$ exactly," not $n\langle x \rangle$.

Comment: No need to worry about the $x_i$ being negative, as the question says $0\le x_i\le1$. 